# Ruby multithreaded ping loses packets only if there is more than one thread

Tags: ruby, linux, multithreading, ping

I wrote a ruby script to ping multiple hosts in parallel and print pairs of [host : result]. This is the script I produced so far:

```
require 'thread'

    out = ""
    queue = Queue.new
    hosts = ["www.google.com", "www.onet.pl", "www.lego.com", "www.example.com"]

    hosts.each do |x|
      queue << x;
    end

    hash = Hash.new "NO REPLY"
    threads = []
    NO_OF_THREADS = 4;

    for i in 1..NO_OF_THREADS
      threads << Thread.new do

        until queue.empty? do
          host = queue.pop(true) rescue nil

          if host
            out = `ping #{host} -c 10 | grep 'packet loss'`
            hash[host] = out
          end

        end # until
      end # thread
    end # for

    threads.each do |t|
        t.join
    end

    puts hash
```

When I set the number of threads to `1`, I get `0% packets lost` responses, but when I try to execute multiple threads at once I get a lot of lost packets. I executed this script with a long list of hosts to check and many threads; the result was that most hosts from my list lost 100% of the packets.

I tried synchronization with a `Mutex` instead of using a `Queue` and adding a `sleep` within the thread, but I didn't help. At this point I'm not sure if there is an issue with my code or I misunderstood how ping is supposed to work. Why am I having a lot of packets lost? Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I am also seeing packet loss, even with just one thread running `ping` in a loop.

Comment: No, sorry, I can't remember finding a solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

The immediate thing that springs to mind is that not all of those hosts are necessarily going to permit ICMP PING messages.

However, I run your code, and get 0% packet loss across the hosts:

```
www.google.com10 packets transmitted, 10 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
www.lego.com10 packets transmitted, 10 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
www.onet.pl10 packets transmitted, 10 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
www.example.com10 packets transmitted, 10 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
```

What are you running your code on?  A virtual machine?  It may be there is some underlying OS issue which is manifesting as lost packets.

Comment: Xubuntu 13.10 on VirtualBox 4.3.6r91406, hosting system Windows 7.
The code should be deployed to different Linux virtual machine(s), so an OS issue seems very distressing.